# HP DeskJet 2632 printer not working in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: printing, hp

I have a problem with the HP DeskJet 2632 printer
It worked fine until I updated the UBUNTU operating system "Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS", that no longer finds the connection USB or wireless.

I downloaded the compressed file "linux-5.9.1.tar.xz" from the site "https://www.kernel.org/" and extracted it, hoping it will help me.

How can I install it now?

Thank you and greetings

Ugo Dentice

Comment: Hey Ugo Sonja! You don't need to mess with kernel stuff for making your printer work. Open terminal, paste this: `apt-cache policy hplip` and press Enter. Copy the output and paste it in your question (use the [edit] feature). If you wanna reply to my comment, don't forget to ping me; like this @technastic_tc

Comment: thank you  technastic_tc
I get the following:
hplip:
  Installato: 3.20.3+dfsg0-2
  Candidato:  3.20.3+dfsg0-2
  Tabella versione:
 *** 3.20.3+dfsg0-2 500
        500 http://ftp.arnes.si/pub/mirrors/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

where I can ping you @technastic_tc   ?

Comment: @UgoSonja Please add your new information as an edit to your post, and not as a comment.  You can "ping" users who have commented to you by simply commenting with [@]USERNAME in the message.

Comment: The question is claimed to have a answer using HPLIP. That could be correct and the user might feel comfortable with going that way. However, closing the question completely ignores the modern driverless printing technique and does the user no favours. So why close the question? Sooner or later it will be realised that HPLIP is redundant. Advising users of modern printers to work with it is not in their best interests.